# URL blocked by whitelist

Tags: android, cordova

For an Angular app I'm trying to build in Cordova, I have this in config.xml:

```
<uri="*" subdomains="true"/>
```

ADB debugger shows the URL is blocked. I've tried putting in the 10.0.0.2 instead of * and a ton of other things as per Stack Overflow answers, to no avail.

Here is the error in the adb debugger listing:

> W/IceCreamCordovaWebViewClient(26882): URL blocked by whitelist: http://10.0.0.2/econ/public_html/e.php?method=attendees

Comment: Possible duplicate of [04-28 16:06:29.756: W/SystemWebViewClient(16778): URL blocked by whitelist:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29913871/04-28-160629-756-w-systemwebviewclient16778-url-blocked-by-whitelist)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead uri

```
<access origin="10.0.0.2"/>
```

Comment: well I don't get that error anymore, yet something else is wrong. it works on the web but not cordova....

Comment: yes, blocked by whitelist is error of Android, just add this line to config.xml in Android project

Answer (score 9):

install [cordova-plugin-whitelist](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist) to resolve this issue

```
$ cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist
$ cordova prepare
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check your gradle verson in build.gradle. I.e. check if the gradle version is existing in maven.org or not (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/). If not, update the version in build.gradle accordingly.