# 04-28 16:06:29.756: W/SystemWebViewClient(16778): URL blocked by whitelist:

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, whitelist, blocked

This problem appeared when I update the ionic and cordova, $http can't normally work any more, always return null. in debug line apeared "04-28 16:06:29.756: W/SystemWebViewClient(16778): URL blocked by whitelist:"

Answer (score 8):

This error happened after cordova **update 5.0.0**.

Like *Santosh* said, you just need add the plugin **https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist.git** to your app and everything will work. I was getting the same error and i fixed with this plugin.

You will need add the follow code to your webconfig file:

```
<allow-navigation href="http://yourDomain.com/*" />
```

Answer (score 6):

With the updated version of cordova-android, you now need to include the cordova-whitelist-plugin.

https://github.com/apache/cordova-mobile-spec/tree/master/cordova-plugin-whitelist

Try adding that to your project

For example -

```
      cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist.git
```

For more help read issue on https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/3597

Answer (score 1):

Use this command with new CLI:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist
```

And in the `config.xml` no need to change the default settings which are:

```
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
```

Here * represents anything so I solved my CORS problem using these settings.

**Note:Don't forget to remove the platform after adding the plugin although it's added automatically there too but it's better to take precaution as you'll never know what might be the cause using**

```
ionic cordova plugin save
ionic cordova platform remove android
ionic cordova platform remove ios
```

Then add again

```
ionic cordova platform add android
ionic cordova platform add ios
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, just try adding whitelist plugin again. As it might be missing as happened with us. So try the following commands

For phonegap build:

```
phonegap plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist
```

for Cordova :

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist
```